# PFUser Query returning same user

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to search for users which match the `searchString`. The only thing I'm getting back is me, the current user. No matter what name I type in I get zero results back, but if I type in part of *my* name then it returns one result with the object (PFUser) representing me when it falls into the `parseMembersFromArray` method. I have tried alternatives but nothing is working.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:searchString modifiers:@"i"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (objects.count < 1) {
        // Zero results
        NSLog(@"No objects found?");
        return;
    }
    if (error) {
        // Error
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong.");
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Good to go
        [self parseMembersFromArray:objects];
    }
}];
```

Comment: You are saying that `parseMembersFromArray` always returns only the currentUser? Can you show its code please.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if its actually returning `currentUser'. But it is me. Do you understand what I'm saying? I updated the question to add that clarification.

Comment: Have you set any ACLs on the user table?  It may be that your current user doesn't have permission to see other users

Comment: I think that's the problem. I did not set them myself, but I think another team member may have. Thanks.